# Can't figure out why the Python IRC library isn't working

Tags: python, irc

I'm trying to make a simple IRC Client using the [IRC library from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/irc).

I tried running both of the sample/template IRC client scripts and came up with errors. Here's a screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUiAl.png]

I can connect to 'irc.freenode.net' with the nick 'quorrabot' and to the channel 'bot_test' in xchat and irssi. Also I tried this command:

```
python irccat2.py irc.freenode.net quorrabot \#bot_testing
```

Aswell as running it as root:

```
sudo python irccat2.py irc.freenode.net quorrabot \#bot_testing
sudo python irccat2.py irc.freenode.net quorrabot bot_testing
```

I'm running Arch Linux x64 if that would mean anything. And Python 3.3.

Comment: The "errors" in your screenshot are due to you hitting `Ctrl+C` to terminate the program. What exactly is the problem? (In passing, *never, ever run a bot as root*.)

Comment: Well it just hangs forever if I don't terminate it =/

Comment: It's supposed to - it's a bot. Did you try connecting to IRC with your own client and interacting with it on the channel?

Comment: Oh I mean that it just hangs and doesn't give me the MOTD or anything. Yes I did. It doesn't output anything. Like the messages on the channel, or MOTD,  etc. Thank you so much for all the help thus far!